# How to automate opening multiple ssh servers with distinct session name in iterm2?

Tags: ssh, applescript, iterm2

[image]

I am automating my developing setup and found an appplescript that opens multiple terminals and ssh into different servers. It works great but I want to change the tab names so that I can distinguish between tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the profile that you are using has the following "Terminal" option set:

[image]

Now you are set the tab and/or window title:

```
tell current session
    write text "echo -ne \"\\033]1; A Tab Title \\007\""
    write text "echo -ne \"\\033]2; A Window Title \\007\""
end tell
```